# Android - custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Could anybody help me solve my problem.
I still trying work with `DraggingListView` and `ArrayAdapter`.
Now i want realize delete element from `listview` by click, but when i making :

```
StableArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

i get `nullPointer Exception` ...

here is my adapter:

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    final int INVALID_ID = -1;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    Context ctx;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.shvedchenko.skleroshop";
    public static final String PREFS_THEME = "theme";

    HashMap<Product, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> prod) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, /*objects*/prod);
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ctx = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < prod.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(prod.get(i), i);
        }
    }


    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getItem(position);

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int theme = pref.getInt(PREFS_THEME, 0);             // getting Integer

        if(theme == 0)
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.getProductName());
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.getProductImage());

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mIdMap.remove(getItem(position));
                System.out.println("FROM CLICK -- " + mIdMap.size() );
                /*for( Product p : mIdMap.keySet() ) {
                    System.out.println( p.getProductName() );
                }*/
                //StableArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    /*@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mIdMap.get(position);
    }*/


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= mIdMap.size()) {
            return INVALID_ID;
        }
        Product item = (Product) getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

here is the error:

> 08-26 08:50:58.902    2167-2167/com.shvedchenko.skleroshop
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(StableArrayAdapter.java:104)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.rememberSyncState(AdapterView.java:1195)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:810)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
>               at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
>               at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
>               at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.StableArrayAdapter$1.onClick(StableArrayAdapter.java:85)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

/*UPDATED*/

My adapter now:

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    final int INVALID_ID = -1;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    Context ctx;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.shvedchenko.skleroshop";
    public static final String PREFS_THEME = "theme";

    HashMap<Product, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Product> prods = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> prod) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, /*objects*/prod);
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ctx = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < prod.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(prod.get(i), i);
            prods.add(i,prod.get(i));
        }
    }


    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getItem(position);

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int theme = pref.getInt(PREFS_THEME, 0);             // getting Integer

        if(theme == 0)
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.getProductName());
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.getProductImage());

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                prods.remove(position);
                StableArrayAdapter.this.notifyData(prods);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void notifyData(List<Product> prod) {

        //First of all Clear Map
        mIdMap.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < prod.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(prod.get(i), i);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= mIdMap.size()) {
            return INVALID_ID;
        }
        Product item = (Product) getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

/*ERROR*/

> 08-26 09:53:19.270    2530-2530/com.shvedchenko.skleroshop E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(StableArrayAdapter.java:122)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.rememberSyncState(AdapterView.java:1195)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:810)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
>               at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
>               at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
>               at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.StableArrayAdapter.notifyData(StableArrayAdapter.java:112)
>               at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.StableArrayAdapter$1.onClick(StableArrayAdapter.java:91)

What i am doing wrong?

TNX in advance!

Comment: add this `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside constructer

Comment: Unfortunately..still the same..

Comment: It would help to know where the exception occurs.

Comment: also post how u create object of StableArrayAdapter in activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct code for adapter:

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    final int INVALID_ID = -1;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    Context ctx;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.shvedchenko.skleroshop";
    public static final String PREFS_THEME = "theme";

    HashMap<Product, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> prod) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, /*objects*/prod);
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ctx = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < prod.size(); i++) {
            mIdMap.put(prod.get(i), i);
        }
    }


    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getItem(position);

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int theme = pref.getInt(PREFS_THEME, 0);             // getting Integer

        if(theme == 0)
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.getProductName());
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.getProductImage());

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StableArrayAdapter.this.remove(getItem(position));
                StableArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= mIdMap.size()) {
            return INVALID_ID;
        }
        Product item = (Product) getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove item from list

```
  list.remove(position);
```

Then call below method using adapter object.

```
  stableAdapter.notifyData(list);
```

Write a method in your Adapter class.

```
  public void notifyData(List<Product> prod)
  {

      //First of all Clear Map
      mIdMap.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < prod.size(); ++i) {
          mIdMap.put(prod.get(i), i);
      }   

      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Call this method using adpater object