# setText not working on Views acquired from ArrayListAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to manipulate a View in an ArrayList adapter. I am using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++){
    TextView busDestTextView = (TextView) busAdapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.busDestinations);
    TextView busNumberTextView = (TextView) busAdapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.busNumber);
    if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(busDestTextView.getText().toString())){
        busNumberTextView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        break;
    }
}
```

The listView consist of horizontal Views having two text views busDestinations and busNumber.
        The setText() method is not changing the text in desired way. It seems to have no effect on the busNumberTextView.

**EDIT:** As other users suggested, these are the codes I have right now.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.busnotifier;
import ...;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseMessaging mFirebaseMessaging;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<Bus>();
    buses.add(new Bus("Dev_Guradiya~Industry_House~Palasia", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Bhavarkua-V", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Boys_hostel~teen_imli~Khajarana", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Khativala~Rani_Sati~Agnibaan~Khajrana", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Kalani_Naga", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Khandwa_naka~Shalimaar~Scheme_54", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("tilak_nagar", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Rani_Sati~Agnibaan~Khajrana~Rani_sati", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Industry_House~Rani_Sati~Agnibaan~Khajrana", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Agnibaan~Khajarana~Rani_Sati", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("PardesipuraVijaynagar", 0));
    buses.add(new Bus("Sai_Mandir~VijayNagar", 0));
    BusAdapter busAdapter= new BusAdapter(this, buses);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach the adapter to the listView.
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.busListView);
    listView.setAdapter(busAdapter);

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Buses").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++){
                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(buses.get(i).getDestinations())){
                    TextView busNumberTextView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.busNumber);
                    busNumberTextView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dataSnapshot.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

**BusAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.busnotifier;

import ....;

public class BusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bus> {
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Buses");
    public BusAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Bus> buses){
        super(context, 0, buses);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View busListItemView = convertView;
        if(busListItemView == null) {
            busListItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        //        TextView for the Bus number
        Bus currentBus = getItem(position);
        final TextView busNumberTextView = (TextView) busListItemView.findViewById(R.id.busNumber);
        busNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentBus.getBusNumber()));

        //        Used EraserRegular font for the bus-stop names
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/KGSecondChancesSolid.ttf");
        busNumberTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);

        //        TextView for the destinations of the corresponding bus-number
        final Button destinationsTextView = (Button) busListItemView.findViewById(R.id.busDestinations);
        destinationsTextView.setText(currentBus.getDestinations());
        destinationsTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        destinationsTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*If the user clicks on a button it will change color and subscribe
                the user to corresponding Topic of the FireBase*/
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Subscribed to: "+destinationsTextView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.buttonClicked);
                destinationsTextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(String.valueOf(destinationsTextView.getText().toString()));
                mDatabaseReference.child(destinationsTextView.getText().toString()).setValue(Integer.parseInt(busNumberTextView.getText().toString()));
                Log.d(">>>>", "onClick: "+destinationsTextView.getText().toString()+"/"+busNumberTextView.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        return busListItemView;
    }
}
```

**ListItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#414141"
android:id="@+id/busListEntry"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/busDestinations"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="@color/buttonColor"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    tools:text="aksjfdkaskdfalsasfasfasfasdasf aslkjfaksjfkjaks dkajsdf asdfajsdfjalksd fasjflkajsdasf asjfkajsdklfjas"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/busNumber"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_background"
    tools:text="1"/>
```

**Bus.java**

```
package com.example.busnotifier;

public class Bus {
    private int busNumber;
    private String destinations;

    public Bus(String destinations, int busNumber) {
        this.busNumber = busNumber;
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public int getBusNumber() {
        return busNumber;
    }

    public String getDestinations() {
        return destinations;
    }

    public void setDestinations(String destinations) {
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public void setBusNumber(int busNumber) {
        this.busNumber = busNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Subclass ListView and override the getView() method to set the text based on the position.

Comment: I am using Firebase Database and want to update the busNumber in ListView if key matches to any of the busDestinations in the listView.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the way to work with listview and adpaters. The update of the information should be done on the adapter  and then refresh the listview.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], which means also your firebase code

Comment: Sorry for being late on updating the question. Please have a look at it now everyone.

Comment: There are a lot of SO posts about proper implementation of ArrayAdapter. In short: You are on the right path but: 1. ListView needs to set OnClickListener(). 2. In 'OnClickListener' obtain the adapter, update the item, then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the listview. Here is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501460/android-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 approaches. 1 you can use listview with onItemClickListener. The alternative is to implement OnItemSelectedListener in your bus array adapter.

I'm a little rusty with android so here is what I recommend:

1. Get your list view and adapter setup:

```
    mAdapter = new BusAdapter();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.my_listview);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

2. Add item click listener to your list view:

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            mAdapter.onBusItemSelected(position);
            Log("Selected item at position " + position);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    });
```

3. In your adapter, add a public function called "onBusItemSelected(int position)" and update your data structures. For example, have a boolean variable labeled "selected". By default it is false.

```
   ...
   void onItemSelected(int position) {
       getItem(position).selected = true;
   }
```

4. Last, your custom ArrayAdapter needs to update the getView() item to look for the new variable and update the text color based on that variable.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)       
       ...
       if (bus.selected) {
          holder.textView.setTextColor(RED);
       } else {
          holder.textView.setTextColor(BLACK);
       }
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put ViewGroup null in `busAdapter.getView(i, null, null)`. You can read: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)