# How to combine multiple ArrayList<Hashmap> values into one ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following diagram for this issue I am facing;
[image]

Here is a sample of the ArrayList in my code;

```
[{name0=Adventurousness, value0=46}, {value1=98, name1=Artistic interests}, {name2=Emotionality, value2=70}, {value3=54, name3=Imagination}, {value4=99, name4=Intellect}, {value5=98, name5=Authority-challenging}, {name0=Achievement striving, value0=62}, {value1=98, name1=Cautiousness}, {name2=Dutifulness, value2=69}, {value3=75, name3=Orderliness}, {value4=44, name4=Self-discipline}, {value5=65, name5=Self-efficacy}, {name0=Activity level, value0=69}, {value1=75, name1=Assertiveness}, {name2=Cheerfulness, value2=0}, {value3=6, name3=Excitement-seeking}, {value4=7, name4=Outgoing}, {value5=0, name5=Gregariousness}, {name0=Altruism, value0=84}, {value1=86, name1=Cooperation}, {name2=Modesty, value2=61}, {value3=81, name3=Uncompromising}, {value4=99, name4=Sympathy}, {value5=54, name5=Trust}, {name0=Fiery, value0=5}, {value1=19, name1=Prone to worry}, {name2=Melancholy, value2=76}, {value3=46, name3=Immoderation}, {value4=72, name4=Self-consciousness}, {value5=18, name5=Susceptible to stress}]
```

You can imagine another similar ArrayList that contains (`name0`,`value0`) values.

I don't know how to achieve this, I tried something like this but didn't work; These are the IDs inside the `ListView` where I want the values in.

```
sample1Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), sample1List2,
R.layout.samplecontent, new String[]{ "name0", "value0",
"name1", "value1", "name2", "value2",
"name3", "value3", "name4", "value4", "name5", "value5"},
new int[]{R.id.name2, R.id.value2, R.id.name3, R.id.value3,
R.id.name4, R.id.value4, R.id.name5, R.id.value5,
R.id.name6, R.id.value6, R.id.name7, R.id.value7});
listview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
listview.setAdapter(sample1Adapter);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look in to this post , may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383330/how-to-combine-two-array-list-and-show-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: I already saw that post. The change is in that question, I want all the data values ("first_data1" etc), under the "firstname1_data1" value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to display 4 key value pairs per row.  Create an object that has those key value pairs, then tie your adapter to a List of those objects.  Suppose the key value pairs represented attributes of a Magazine:

```
class Magazine implements Parcelable 
String publisher;
String title;
int numCopiesAvailable;
int numCopiesSold;

String getPublisher()
```

Pass the List of type Magazine to your custom adapter and inside it render each element.  One row with the 4 attributes are displayed per row

Comment: Can you answer my question please. This makes no sense.

Comment: It answers your question.   If you want to show 4 key value pairs per row, create a model that represents it, then render it through a recyclerview.  A recyclerview needs an adapter, so pass a List of that model to the adapter.  You are making an easy problem difficult

Comment: The question is how. I have all the variables, data in the question. If you can't answer the question properly, please refrain from writing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Instead of `SimpleAdapter` use `ArrayAdapter` where pass your `ArrayList<HashMap>` object

Solution2:
Create your custom adapter and its constructor pass your `ArrayList<HashMap>` object and handle data inside it to load into your `ListView`

Comment: This may help you
Solution 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501460/android-custom-arrayadapter
Solution 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324491/fill-a-custom-list-view-with-custom-adapter-array-list-and-hashmap-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Support there are 3 `ArrayList<HashMap>` than put them to into one finalList.

Take another

```
 ArrayList<HashMap> finalList = new HashMap();
```

you can take a loop an add all to this final List

```
finalList.put("0",haspMapList1);
finalList.put("1",haspMapList2);
```

Than pass this list in your CustomListAdapter.